# How can i add multiple delegates to my view controller?

Tags: ios

How can i add multiple delegates to my view controller? I need to have multiple delegates, `<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>` and `<UITextViewDelegate>`. This is my current system for it which only allows me to have one:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface FifthViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *subjectfield;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *explainfield;
- (IBAction)sendbutton:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *BCCfield;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;



@end
```

Ive tried doing things like using commas and spaces but i get the error "expected identifier" when i have multiple delegates in there.

Comment: Comma separated is fine, be sure to import any frameworks/classes you need that define the delegates.

Comment: Just a clarification - you are not adding delegates here. You are telling the compiler that your view controller conforms to the listed protocols (MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate and UITextViewDelegate). You are not adding delegates to your view controller, you are going to make your view controller a delegate of an MFMailComposeViewController and a UITextView.

Answer (score 3):

You should have comma separated protocols inside the `<>` brackets. E.g.

```
@interface FifthViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 1):

With a comma.

```
@interface MyViewControllerName : UIViewController <ProtocolOne, ProtocolTwo,
   ProtocolThree, ProtocolFour, IveSeenAsManyAsTenProtocols, YouCanAddAllYouWant>
```

The header files for these protocols must be imported.

Comment: what if I have  two controllers to delegate from?
for eg: `@interface MyViewControllerName : UIViewController <ProtocolOne, ProtocolTwo>, CustomController<protocolthree>`

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: : Please have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868165/inherit-delegate-methods-from-custom-class-and-uiviewcontroller-objective-c/38868420?noredirect=1#comment65100805_38868420)