# Inherit delegate methods from custom class and UIViewController (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a main controller which implements methods from a custom class. Now in the main controller I want to add a table within an alert view for which I need to implement UITableView delegate methods. I want to implement something like below

[image]

On Clicking the `Click Here` Button, an alert view is displayed which contains a table displaying all the items.

CustomController is defined like below

`@interface CustomController : UIViewController`

### PRESENT

**in .h file**

`@interface mainController : CustomController<CustomDelegateMethod>`

**in .m file**

`@interface mainController()`

### REQUIRED

**in .h file**

`@interface mainController : CustomController<CustomDelegateMethod>`

// I want to add `UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` to the above line.

AlertView code in MainController:

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"List of Items" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Back" otherButtonTitles:@"Add New Item", nil];

    tableView = [([UITableView alloc])initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [av addSubview:tableView];
    [av show];
```

How can I implement delegate methods from different controllers? 
Because When I add 
`@interface mainController : CustomController<CustomDelegateMethod>,UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` 
it is throwing an error `Expected identifier or '('` 
and if I add the tableview delegate methods like this 
`@interface mainController : CustomController<CustomDelegateMethod,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` , delegate methods are not called when I run the application.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

in .h file

```
@interface mainController : CustomController
```

in .m file

```
@interface mainController() <CustomDelegateMethod,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property(nonatomic,strong)UITableView * tableView;

@end

UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"List of Items" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Back" otherButtonTitles:@"Add New Item", nil];

UITableView *tableView = [([UITableView alloc])initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView = tableView;
[av addSubview:tableView];
[av show];
```

Comment: as of now not throwing any errors but when I run the code, not calling the delegate methods in .m file.  (I have tried similar way but i added the delegate methods in .h file)

Comment: no result :( Don't know if my delegate methods calling is correct or not